# calculating an average from database values

Tags: php, sql

If I wish to calculate the average value of an attribute from values stored in a database is it better to do this using sql code or php code.  Please give reasons why.

Comment: ONLY sql because of performance - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp (you dont need to fetch all data)

Comment: Write a query and check.

Comment: It probably depends on a number of factors, size of data set, availability of indexes on the fields you want to make calculations for, how well the data is structured in the database to begin with, etc.  Your question as it stands now is very open ended, and not really a question to which a concrete answer can be given.

Comment: How the *hell* is this question too broad?! It's a very apt question with a VERY succinct **and singularly definite** correct answer: Use SQL function, that's what it's designed for, way way better than PHP. Just make sure the column is indexed. Closers are so wrong on this one!

Answer (score 2):

You should use MySQL functions, they are often faster than doing it with php, because you don't have to iterate through all results.

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/06/23/mysql-has-functions-part-5-php-vs-mysql-performance/